# Is GlassFish redeploy supposed to work?

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, glassfish-3

This is with GF 3.1.1 build 12.

I have a JSF 2 web application that uses EclipseLink 2.3.0 as the back end JPA provider.  You can see the deployment [here](http://www.myqwip.com).

When I use the admin console to redeploy, it uploads the WAR file just fine, then all hell breaks loose.  As soon as someone accesses a page the log fills with exceptions usually related to attempting to do operations on a closed EntityManager.  If I let it go on, GlassFish degenerates and pretty much crashes -- I can't get any response anymore on the admin port.

If I do a reload, then it seems to work OK.  So my question is, what kind of application can do a redeploy without a reload?   Is there something I can do to my application to let do a smooth transition from one version to the next?

Comment: I can't comment on glassfish itself, but the error mentioned with EntityManagers might occur if the app is using resource local and not closing its EntityManagerFactory instances when redeployed.